# Calling Update-MgPlace cmdlet not working

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to patch a Place using the cmdlet Update-MgPlace

```
$addProp = @{
floorNumber = 1
capacity = 15
}

Update-MgPlace -PlaceId <myRoomId> -AdditionalProperties $addProp
```

Getting this error

> Update-MgPlace_UpdateExpanded : Update request has to be for a tenant Room or RoomList.
> Au caractère C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.Graph.Calendar\1.9.0\exports\v1.0\ProxyCmdletDefinitions.ps1:17598 : 23
> $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters}
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation : ({ PlaceId = c62...oftGraphPlace }:<>f__AnonymousType872) [Update-MgPlace_UpdateExpanded], RestException1
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.UpdateMgPlace_UpdateExpanded
> ```

With the same administrator account and required permissions, I sucessfully update the Place using Graph Explorer :

- EndPoint : PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/
- Headers : Content-type = Application/JSON
- Body :

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.room",
    "capacity": "15",
    "floorNumber": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `-BodyParameter` instead of `-AdditionalProperties`.

In the request body, use `@odata.type` to specify the type of place.

```
$params = @{
"@odata.type" = "microsoft.graph.room"
floorNumber = 1
capacity = 15
}

Update-MgPlace -PlaceId <myRoomId> -BodyParameter $params
```

Comment: I also tried this but my mistake was to write "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.room" with a "#"...
Thanks mate !